# Primary display is not being detected after installing Nvidia driver

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, additional-drivers

The laptop which I'm using is Acer Predator Helios 300 (i5 8th gen). The specs of my laptop are:

- GPU: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti
- Ubuntu version: 18.04.4 LTS
- Dual boot: Windows 10 and Ubuntu
- Current driver: nvidia-driver-450(open source)

Primary display is not being detected; only secondary monitor is working after adding the Nvidia driver.

Initially it was working fine. For some work I had to switch to Windows. After sometime, I switched back to Ubuntu; suddenly laptop's display is not being detected.

I don't know what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem

write in terminal and reboot

```
cd /etc/X11
sudo rm xorg.conf
sudo cp xorg.conf.nvidia-xconfig-original xorg.conf
reboot
```